# Getting error after deleting .grails folder from home in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I mistakenly deleted .grails folder from home. Now when I run the grails application, it comes with many errors saying plugins not founds. I want to know is there any way to sort this out ?
The error is as following

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:csv:0.3.1
- org.grails.plugins:kickstart-with-bootstrap:0.9.6
- org.grails.plugins:joda-time:1.4
- org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0.1
```

I had uninstalled the `csv` and `quartz` plugins better before the deletion of that folder but they are also in error. My `buildConfig.groovy` does not contain any dependencies.

Comment: Does your app try to download this plugins or just exit after error? Can you show output?

Comment: Yes it does but fails. I want to know whether the application will be able to run in some way after deleting that folder ?

Comment: I should work after deleting, it's a cache + optional configs. Please show output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.grails` is a cache folder, so you're safe to delete it. This is also recommended when you upgrade the Grails version and start to see some errors.

Normally when you do it, you need to refresh the dependencies of your project, to make sure that all dependencies are downloaded. You can do it from the command line:

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: this command gives this error. | Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

Comment: try a `clean` before the compile. If this not solves your error, change the log level in the BuildConfig as mentioned by the message.

Comment: You running in Eclipse/GGTS or from a command prompt? Try the command prompt as it rules out an IDE timing out connections to remote servers as there will be a lot to download.